# char data type on sailsjs (waterline orm)

Tags: mysql, orm, sails.js, waterline

Is there a way to set *"char"* data type on Sails.js or waterline orm for mysql? In Sails.js documentation (http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes), there is no char type. There is *"string"*, but it's for varchar.

Comment: same string is for char too!

Comment: You can set type: 'string', size: '20'